# How can fixed element push content down the page using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've seen similar question asked here before but answers usually include Jquery etc. I'm rookie and I want to use CSS only.
I have a web page and there is a text displayed on it:

```
<P>yes yes yes </P>
<P>yes yes yes </P>
<P class="move">Moving part</P>
```

I want the last part (class move) to move on the top when screen is small. This works great:

```
.move {
    color: blue;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .move {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

Except "Moving part" is displayed over text! How can I push the text down. I've tried height, etc.

Comment: When you're using `position:fixed` the element is taken out of the normal document flow, and therefore will not take up additional space. You will have to use a placeholder element, or clone the element such that its original parent remains relative (but rendered transparent in narrow screens), or give the immediate sibling (using `+`) a top margin that matches the height of the fixed element. There is a proposed `position: sticky` that does exactly what you want, but [it is still not widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky).

Comment: inside your mediaquerie you could add some padding to body or some margin to another element. Your question doesn't tell enough to really answer properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is [`position: sticky`](http://caniuse.com/#search=sticky), but it's only supported in FireFox and Safari.

Unfortunately there is no way to mimic this for other browsers without JavaScript.

To do this requires the top to be calculated and modified as you scroll down the page. I've looked for a CSS only solution myself and it doesn't seem to exist, nor did my attempts work.

Have a look at the [stickyMojo](http://mojotech.github.io/stickymojo/) jQuery plugin or [Bootstrap affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

Comment: Support for this feature has grown and can now be used in all major browsers except one. Guess which.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code into a div and give it a margin-top when the screen gets smaller. That´s the only thing i could imagine that could work in all browsers  with only using CSS. Your "move"-element should have a fixed height then. For example:

```
<div class="move-mobile">
  <P>yes yes yes </P>
  <P>yes yes yes </P>
</div>
<P class="move">Moving part</P>
```

CSS

```
.move {
    color: blue;
    height: 50px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .move {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .move-mobile {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
}
```

or make two move elements, the one is hidden and only gets visible when the screen gets smaller, the other one is hidden then.