# Hide/Show Navbar not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I can't seem to get this right.  I've looked for hours for a solution.

I needed to remove position: fixed; in order for my navBar to push content down when menu is opened.  The problem is now when I scroll down, the navBar disappears as it should, but when I scroll back up it should reappear immediately. Instead it reappears only when I reach the top of the page.  This behavior only started when position: fixed; was commented out. Any insight into how I can fix this would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio2.css">

  <!-- <script async src="https://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script> -->

  <title>Portfolio 2</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="masthead" class="nav-down">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Vernon Blankenhorn</a>
      <button id="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Me <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <div id="alpha">
    <div id="text" class="container pt-5">
      <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis          in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit            amet ligula. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta.              Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac              lectus.
      </p>

      <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Proin eget tortor risus. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Sed            porttitor lectus nibh. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis          in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit            amet ligula.
      </p>

      <p>Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Proin eget tortor risus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus magna          justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Cras ultricies ligula sed          magna dictum porta.
      </p>

      <p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Curabitur non          nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget            felis porttitor volutpat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor                volutpat. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.
      </p>

      <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,                consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Sed porttitor lectus            nibh. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Mauris blandit aliquet elit,            eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Proin eget tortor risus.
      </p>

      <p>Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec            rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a.            Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Pellentesque in            ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec            velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh              pulvinar a.
      </p>

      <p>Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh              pulvinar a. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget                  tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed,            convallis at tellus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit.
      </p>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Sed            porttitor lectus nibh. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh                pulvinar a. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec,            egestas non nisi. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.              Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.
      </p>

      <p>Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Praesent sapien            massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis          a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Nulla quis              lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat.
      </p>

      <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus suscipit                rices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Donec rutrum                congue leo eget malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas          non nisi.
      </p>

      <p> Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit             tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Curabitur aliquet quam           id dui posuere blandit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.
      </p>

      <p>Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Lorem ipsum              dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl          tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Praesent sapien          massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="portfolio2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler{
  border: none!important;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover, .navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 2px solid gray;
}

#masthead {
/*   position: fixed; */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform 450ms ease;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
  transform: translateY(-100%)
}

/* .bg {
  /* The image used
  background-image: url("https://cdn42.picsart.com/167005229000201.jpeg?r1024x1024");
} */

html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url(https://cdn42.picsart.com/167005229000201.jpeg?r1024x1024) ;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:  cover;
    background-color: #999;
/*   padding-top: 56px; */
}

#alpha{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

/* .myClass {
  transition: transform 400ms ease;
  transform: translateY(5%);
} */
```

JavaScript:

```
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    didScroll = true;
});

// How long should we listen to the scroll before acting?
setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
      hasScrolled();
      didScroll = false;
  }
}, 100);


function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
      return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
      // Scroll Down
      $('#masthead').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
      // Scroll Up
      if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
          $('#masthead').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
      }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}

 $('#button').on('click', function() {
   $('#alpha').toggleClass('myClass');
});

// $('#button').on("click", function() {
//    $('#alpha').slideToggle(1000);
//  });
```

If I put the position: fixed; back in, my problem is fixed, but then the content is no longer pushed down when menu is opened. Instead, the navBar overlaps the content and doesn't push it down. Is there a way to fix this without just simply adding padding? Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is a fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LouieB/bcd9qa8x/42/)

Comment: So you basically want the nav bar to be hidden while scrolling down but otherwise be visible? Or visible when scrolling up? When should the nav bar be visible?

Comment: Hey Anthony, the navbar disappearing on scroll down and reappearing instantly on scroll up works perfect.(when I have the navbar position set to fixed).  My question is more about why this breaks(navbar only appears when I reach the top) when I remove the fixed attribute.  The reason for removing it was to get the menu to push down content of page when opening it.  I hope this makes sense.

Comment: it probably breaks when removing `fixed` because it is no longer fixed to the browser window, but instead takes its normal position in the document. So the real problem is that when the navbar is visible, it hides the content it is on top of instead of pushing it down?

Comment: Correct.  Content is hidden when navbar is visible. Not using fixed fixes this, but also messes with my navbar animation, and using it breaks the part of pushing content down, but fixes the animation.  It's a two part problem really. Check out the fiddle.

Comment: The problem isn't with `fixed`, so get that out of your head. The whole thing ceases to work without `fixed`, as it should. The problem is that you want the navbar to push down the content when it comes into view. One tricky thing about that is that you can't reliably tell the window to scroll down using `window.scrollBy(0, navbarHeight)` because that triggers a new scroll event, which calls your scroll handler again. Still tinkering...

Comment: Apparently, this can be done in some browsers using `position: sticky`, but it's not supported in all browsers. But if you look that up, there are polyfills with JS you could use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782665/how-can-fixed-element-push-content-down-the-page-using-css-only

Comment: Thanks Anthony...I'll look into that and report anything that helps.

Comment: Changing the `margin-top` when the masthead becomes visible seems to work (but I'm not sure how to make it based on the masthead's height without hard-coding it like I did). http://jsfiddle.net/bcd9qa8x/96/

Comment: UPDATE: I tried position: sticky; and so far it seems to work. The scrolling works properly, and opening menu pushes content down. But , I'm using JSFiddle in chrome on my phone.  I will test in browsers tomorrow and report back